# Finding midpoint of rectangle in 3D vectors

Tags: analytic-geometry, vectors

If given the points (-10,-2,0), (-10,2,0), (-12,0,2) and (-12,0,-2), how do I find the midpoint?

Comment: What do you call "midpoint of rectangle" to?! The point of the diagonals' intersection? And what have you done so far to solve this problem?

Comment: do you mean the center of gravity? but then, are these four points planar?

Comment: @Timbuc I was looking at the diagonals' intersection yes and to find the point of intersection at each corner first I tried using dot product = 0 since they are perpendicular and ended up with a single digit answer and not a diagonal equation?

Comment: @abel sorry am not too sure what centre of gravity or planar points mean but it's a vector problem in 3D that requires finding a line straight through the centre of the above mentioned 4 points. but I'm not sure how to find the centre

Comment: @LucasCK But then it seems you're trying to work here with  a rectangular box or cuboid, **not** a (planar) rectangle!

Comment: @Timbuc if possibly that, do you have a recommended solution? no luck so far

Comment: I don't know, @LucasCK . Are the points you wrote vertices of the cuboid? Is there a pair of them which is an opposite pair of vertices?

Comment: What are you even looking for? Those 4 points are not co-planar so they do not make up a rectangle, but a tetrahedron.

Answer (score 1):

the formula for the midpoint if given two points is given by
$$M\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2};\frac{y_1+y_2}{2};\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\right)$$

Comment: I thought of this but it finds two separate midpoints horizontally and vertically, and not one that's in the middle of the 4 lines

Answer (score 1):

The centroid of any *n* points is simply the average of the vectors defining them.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, could you show with an example or have a website to recommend?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid

Comment: It looks plausible but it wasn't covered in my lessons so there might be an alternative way to solve it but thanks for it nonetheless

Comment: For example, in 2 dimensions, the centroid of the three points (1, 20), (6, 7) and (103, 102) is the point ((1+6+103)/3, (20+7+102)/3).

Comment: is that applicable in three-dimensions as well, meaning for example the x-coordinate (-10+-10+-12+-12)/4 = -11 while y and z are = 0?

Comment: Yes! You are quite correct!